# Django Model Many-to-Many and Bridge Tables

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to understand how to properly setup my models in order to have a many-to-many relationship, I noticed that there is a ManyToManyField option while creating models but I can't seem to understand the logic of it and how to properly make it work. I'd like to share my code and explain along the way.

```
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    majors = models.ManyToManyField(Major)

class Professor(models.Model):
    ProfessorIDS = models.IntegerField()
    ProfessorName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ProfessorRating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    NumberOfRatings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Notice that the School TABLE (Class) has a many-to-many for Majors, which is essentially what I want, the goal to have a database allowed to store multiple majors under an individual school.

After doing some research I've come to conclusion that this doesn't make sense, it would be better to create a Bridge Table So I decided to create my model like so...

```
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, db_index=True)


class School_Majors(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Professor(models.Model):
    ProfessorIDS = models.IntegerField()
    ProfessorName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ProfessorRating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    NumberOfRatings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Wouldn't this be a more proper way to setup the db in order to add and remove multiple majors from schools and vice versa?

Comment: There is essentially no difference between your two snippets.  What advantage are you under the impression that you gain from explicitly defining the `School_Majors` model?  (Also as a code style point, use `UpperCamelCase` for classes, and singular names for models).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It would be better to create a Bridge Table

That's what a `ManyToManyField` does.  Your two snippets are functionally identical.

In the case where you might want some extra data on the through table (as it's called in the Django world), such as a field recording when a major was first offered, you can use the `through` argument on the `ManyToManyField`, like so:

```py
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)


class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    majors = models.ManyToManyField(Major, through='SchoolMajor')


class SchoolMajor(models.Model):
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_offered = models.DateField()
```

Adapted from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: I thought that the bridge db wasn't going to be created, Thank you for clearing that up. Do you have any recommendations on how I would be able to populate the bridge table? I'm going to have xlsx/csv files with data that will populate those databases, but I can't figure out the formatting and what tools to use to populate that data, vs manually entering each one in.

Comment: A `for` loop in the shell provided by `./manage.py shell` will do fine for local development and testing.  If this is something you'll need to do often, consider turning it into a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).  As for actually creating the data itself, create all the `Major`s, create all the `School`s, then for each school or major, do `school.majors.add(major)` or `major.schools.add(school)` depending on which you chose.

Comment: You could also turn the data, once initially created, into a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) with `./manage.py dumpdata`, which can be restored to a different database later with `./manage.py loaddata`.

Comment: What if I have this data in a xlsx file, i did some data scrapping off a website and obtained a large amount of data like thousands of rows, and I essentially want to orient this data in such a way in order for it to just populate that database, this fixture is interesting but I feel it would take a very long time for me to format that data. I've used a population script which worked like a charm for xlsx file formats, for sqlite3, but Since this is going to consist of 3 different tables (one being a many-to-many) I wanted to see if there was any other shortcuts out there.

Comment: It's as I said - a `for` loop in the shell for local development and testing, then make a management command if you need to do it more than once.