# How to join multiple table with ForeignKey in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

```
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    EMP_CODE = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    EMP_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...etc

class EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    EMP_CODE = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    EMP_LINK = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    EMP_ADDRESS = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ..etc

class EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_DETAILS(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    EMP_CODE = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    EMP_LINK = models.ForeignKey(EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL)
    EMP_COMPANY_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    NO_OF_WORKING_DAY = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ..etc
```

In here I have EMP_CODE how to get all table data value in single query in orm .for eg( I need EMP_NAME ,EMP_ADDRESS ,EMP_COMPANY_NAME ) Using EMP_CODE . I beginner of python Django

Comment: As I can understand you got (1:1) relationship among `Employee : Employee_Personal` models [One to one field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/),  And between `Employee:Employee_Company_Details` you have(m:1) relationship.[Many to one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). Your schema is confusing I think you need to design your DB first properly.

Comment: in employee table just update name,emp_code,register_date..etc and employee personal details table we store 30 column and employee_company_details also store 30 column so how use manytomany for three table @AvishkaDambawinna

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451057/8388057)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForiegnKey` because you have fields which are related to only one thing.

Comment: sry plzz can you explain that what should do? @Bharat Naik

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try your best to give an explanation when you're answering a question.[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)